# Remove last character if it's a backslash

Tags: python, string

Is there a function to chomp last character in the string if it's some special character? For example, I need to remove backslash if it's there, and do nothing, if not. I know I can do it with regex easily, but wonder if there something like a small built-in function for that.

Comment: What if there are multiple backslashes at the end of the string? Remove them all?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Use `rstrip` to strip the specified character(s) from the right side of the string.

```
my_string = my_string.rstrip('\\')
```

See: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip

Comment: ...and it will remove more than one character if there is more than one backslash at the end of the string.

Comment: @Tim: Good point... I guess the OP should clarify (from my understanding it should remove all the "special characters").

Comment: If this is about normalizing path names, the OS-neutral way to do it is to use strip as said above, but the character to strip is os.sep -- that's backslash for Windows, forward slash for Unix.

Answer (score 26):

If you don't mind all trailing backslashes being removed, you can use [`string.rstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip)

For example:

```
x = '\\abc\\'
print x.rstrip('\\')
```

prints:

```
\abc
```

But there is a slight problem with this (based on how your question is worded): This will strip ALL trailing backslashes. If you really only want the LAST character to be stripped, you can do something like this:

```
if x[-1] == '\\': x = x[:-1]
```

Answer (score 15):

If you only want to remove *one* backslash in the case of multiple, do something like:

```
s = s[:-1] if s.endswith('\\') else s
```

Answer (score 9):

The rstrip function will remove more than just the last character, though. It will remove all backslashes from the end of the string. Here's a simple if statement that will remove just the last character:

```
if s[-1] == '\\':
    s = s[:-1]
```

Answer (score 9):

```
if s.endswith('\\'):
    s = s[:-1]
```

Comment: Did you try this? It's a syntax error. You need to use `if s.endswith('\\')`

Comment: Seriously I run into that every time. What the hell is the point of raw strings if they don't work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Or not so beautiful(don't beat me) but also works:

```
stripSlash = lambda strVal: strVal[:-1] if strVal.endswith('\\') else strVal
stripSlash('sample string with slash\\')
```

And yes - rstrip is better. Just want to try.

Answer (score 1):

We can use built-in function **replace**

**my_str.replace(my_char,'')**

```
my_chars = '\\'    
my_str = my_str.replace(my_char,'')
```

This will replace all **\** in ***my_str***

**my_str.replace(my_chars, '',i)**

```
my_char = '\\'
my_str = 'AB\CD\EF\GH\IJ\KL'
print ("Original my_str : "+ my_str)
for i in range(8):
    print ("Replace '\\' %s times" %(i))
    print("     Result : "+my_str.replace(my_chars, '',i))
```

This will replace **\** in my_str **i** times
Now you can control how many times you want to replace it with **i**

Output:

```
Original my_str : AB\CD\EF\GH\IJ\KL
Replace '\' 0 times
     Result : AB\CD\EF\GH\IJ\KL
Replace '\' 1 times
     Result : ABCD\EF\GH\IJ\KL
Replace '\' 2 times
     Result : ABCDEF\GH\IJ\KL
Replace '\' 3 times
     Result : ABCDEFGH\IJ\KL
Replace '\' 4 times
     Result : ABCDEFGHIJ\KL
Replace '\' 5 times
     Result : ABCDEFGHIJKL
Replace '\' 6 times
     Result : ABCDEFGHIJKL
Replace '\' 7 times
     Result : ABCDEFGHIJKL
```

Answer (score -1):

For C# people who end up here:

```
my_string = my_string.TrimEnd('\\');
```